# Screenshot of a VC that is not on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, screenshot

I need to take an screenshot of a view that is part of another view controller which is not on the screen.

I believe that I need to create that VC, fill it with the correct data, "render it" and then take the screenshot, how could I do so?

This is my current code which is triggering the viewDidLoad() from the target VC but is producing a blank image:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShareVC") as! ShareTransactionViewController
    vc.transaction = self.transaction

    vc.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, true, 0.0)

    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let imageToShare = [ image ]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After some work I managed to find a solution, it might not be the best one so if anyone has a better approach I would appreciate it.

I added a view into the current view controller so I could add the target view into it. I capture the image and then remove the view I added so the current VC looks the same as it was.

```
func share(sender:UIBarButtonItem){

    // Create the VC that has the view we are going to share
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShareVC") as! ShareTransactionViewController
    vc.transaction = self.transaction

    // Prepare the image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.snap.bounds.size, true, 0.0)

    // Draw the view we want to share from the created VC into the current VC
    vc.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.snap.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // Adds the view from the other vc to the snap of the current VC
    self.snap.insertSubview(vc.view, at:0)

    // Redraws all the views of this vc
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // Defining the variable for activityItems
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let imageToShare = [ image ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    // set up activity view controller
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view  // so iPads won't crash

    // Present the view controllet that shares the content
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Removes added subview in current VC
    for view in self.snap.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Comment: It is illegal to grab a view controller's view and just stuff it into a superview without doing the child view controller "dance".

Comment: @matt I am not sure how to take your comment, are you saying that what I did is "right" or that what I am doing is  "illegal" ?